# Replace matches in a file with a hashed value

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I stumbled upon a problem where I have a big weakness. I don't have ninja bash, awk, sed, etc. skills required to accomplish this:

I am working with a Freeradius users file where you have usernames, passwords and other settings stored for a VPN client. So the records in this file are of this format:

```
vpnclient       Cleartext-Password := "ComplexPassword"
                Service-Type = Outbound-User,
                Framed-IP-Address = 172.16.0.225,
                Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.255,
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:inacl=IPSEC_EXTRANET",
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:dns-servers=192.168.1.31 192.168.1.32",
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:split-dns=mydomain.com",
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:split-dns=yourdomain.com"
```

I want to extract `Cleartext-Password := "ComplexPassword"` bits from these and replace the password with a corresponding MD5 hash value. Also I want to replace `Cleartext-Password` to `MD5-Password` at the same time. So after processing I want the records in file to look like this:

```
vpnclient       MD5-Password := "be2cb07387a0574f11772a5b3540845c"
                Service-Type = Outbound-User,
                etc.
```

So really, I just want to find a regex match, process it and plunk it instead of original value in a file. I think this would be handy to know in many many other cases too. The problem is, I don't know if it's even possible to, e.g. use an external command or function in  substitute part of sed and similar stuff.

Comment: You don't have to have ninja skill just to start and give it a try. :-) Questions including attempts at the solution (no matter how buggy) are often answered more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/Cleartext-Password/{
    match($0,/"(.*)"/,a)
    passw=a[1]
   ("echo "passw " | md5sum") |& getline var
   split (var,b)
   sub(/".*"/,"\""b[1]"\"")
} 1 ' input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk -F' *:= *' '$1~/Cleartext-Password/{gsub(/"/, "", $2); printf "%s := \"", $1;
    system("md5 <<< \"" $2 "\"|tr -d \"\\n\""); print "\"";next}1' vpnfile

vpnclient       Cleartext-Password := "be2cb07387a0574f11772a5b3540845c"
                Service-Type = Outbound-User,
                Framed-IP-Address = 172.16.0.225,
                Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.255,
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:inacl=IPSEC_EXTRANET",
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:dns-servers=192.168.1.31 192.168.1.32",
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:split-dns=mydomain.com",
                Cisco-AVPair += "ipsec:split-dns=yourdomain.com"
```